# Principal user (Id=GUID, type = 8) is missing prvRead[entity name] privilege (Id=GUID)

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We have recently migrated from CRM 2011 RU 8 to RU 18. I am trying to retrieve a custom entity records by SOAP call. Its working fine with the user who belongs to root Business Unit and having System Administrator role. But the same code is not working for any other users who belongs to any of the BUs with any roles(even for System Administrator) its giving error: **Principal user (Id=GUID, type = 8) is missing prvRead[entity name] privilege (Id=GUID)**

Need help if you have any idea on this issue.

SOAP Code:

```
RetrieveMultiple = function(entity, attribute, condition)
{
    // Usage => RetrieveMultiple("new_entityname", "new_attribute1|new_attribute2|new_attribute3", "new_attribute1||value1||new_attribute2|Like|value2||new_attribute|NotNull";
    // Refer to the following link for more operators >> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959309.aspx

    // Prepare variables to retrieve the records.
    var attributes = attribute.split('|');
    var authenticationHeader = GenerateAuthenticationHeader();

    // Prepare the SOAP message.
    var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'" +
    " xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" +
    " xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>" +
    authenticationHeader +
    "<soap:Body>" +
    "<RetrieveMultiple xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>" +
    "<query xmlns:q1='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query'" +
    " xsi:type='q1:QueryExpression'>" +
    "<q1:EntityName>" + entity + "</q1:EntityName>" +
    "<q1:ColumnSet xsi:type='q1:ColumnSet'>" +
    "<q1:Attributes>";

    for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++)
        xml += "<q1:Attribute>" + attributes[i] + "</q1:Attribute>"

    xml +=
    "</q1:Attributes>" +
    "</q1:ColumnSet>" +
    "<q1:Distinct>false</q1:Distinct>" +
    "<q1:Criteria>" +
    "<q1:FilterOperator>And</q1:FilterOperator>" +
    "<q1:Conditions>";


    var conditionDetails;
    var conditions = condition.split('||');
    for (i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++) {
        conditionDetails = conditions[i].split('|');
        xml +=
        "<q1:Condition>" +
        "<q1:AttributeName>" + conditionDetails[0] + "</q1:AttributeName>" +
        "<q1:Operator>" + conditionDetails[1] + "</q1:Operator>";

        if (conditionDetails.length > 2) {
            xml +=
            "<q1:Values>" +
            "<q1:Value xsi:type='xsd:string'>" + conditionDetails[2] + "</q1:Value>" +
            "</q1:Values>";
        }

        xml +=
        "</q1:Condition>";
    }

    xml +=
    "</q1:Conditions>" +
    "</q1:Criteria>" +
    "</query>" +
    "</RetrieveMultiple>" +
    "</soap:Body>" +
    "</soap:Envelope>";
    // Prepare the xmlHttpObject and send the request.
    var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    xHReq.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
    xHReq.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/RetrieveMultiple");
    xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
    xHReq.send(xml);
    // Capture the result.
    var resultXml = xHReq.responseXML;

    // Check for errors.
    var errorCount = resultXml.selectNodes('//error').length;
    if (errorCount != 0) {
        var msg = resultXml.selectSingleNode('//description').nodeTypedValue;
        //alert(msg);
        return msg;
    }
    // Parse and display the results.
    else {
        var results = resultXml.getElementsByTagName('BusinessEntity');
        var msg = "";
        if (results.length == 0) {
            //msg = "No record found with the given criteria.";
            //alert(msg);
            //return;
            return null;
        }
        else {
            var result = "";
            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (i != 0)
                    result += '|';
                for (j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++) {
                    if (i != 0 || j != 0)
                        result += '|';
                    if (results[i].selectSingleNode('./q1:' + attributes[j]) != null)
                        result += results[i].selectSingleNode('./q1:' + attributes[j]).nodeTypedValue;
                }

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you have the user access the record via the UI, and not via your custom SOAP call?

Comment: I am able to access the that entity records from UI. And I tried to retrieve other entity records with same SOAP call. But its not working too.

Comment: So a user can access the record from the UI but when the same user makes a SOAP call for the record they get a privilege error? That would indicate something is wrong in your SOAP call. Can you post the code and SOAP making the call?

Comment: Please have look at the SOAP code in the post. Same code working fine for other user(default admin user).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that ended up being permissions based.  The business unit that we were trying to make owner had role of Customer Service Representative and that role didn't have permission on the custom entity (hence the error).

I went to the business unit -> then manage roles -> then clicked the role -> then added create capabilities to the role for the custom entity and that then resolved this issue for us.